# Starting and stopping two recycler views together

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement two horizontal recycler views on a single layout, let's say **recycler_view_1** and **recycler_view_2**, one below the other. I want to implement a functionality in which when **recycler_view_1** scrolls, **recycler_view_2** also scrolls and the moment user stops **recycler_view_1** scrolling **recycler_view_2** also stops.

Currenlty, am able to scroll both of them simultaneously by implementing `onTouchListener`. But when user makes a fling gesture on **recycler_view_1** and immediately stops it by tapping **recycler_view_1**, **recycler_view_2** doesn't stop, rather it completes its scrolling and then stops.

Is there a way to achieve immediate stop of both the views together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same layouts for viewholder (height/width) then you can try next:

```
    recycler_view_1.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            recycler_view_2.scrollBy(dx, dy);
        }
    });
```